# How to check my conditions on react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I need check my conditions on react hooks when startup or change value
I try that by this code but I cant run without Btn

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import { Notifications} from 'expo';
export default function NotificationsTest() {
  const y = 5;
  const askPermissionsAsync = async () => {
    await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.USER_FACING_NOTIFICATIONS);
  };
  const btnSendNotClicked = async () => {
    if(y===5){
      await askPermissionsAsync();
      Notifications.presentLocalNotificationAsync({
        title: "Title",
        body: "****** SUBJ *******",
        ios:{
          sound:true,
        },
        android:{
          sound:true,
          color:'#512da8',
          vibrate:true,
        }
     });
    }else{ 
    }    }
  useEffect(()=>{
    return btnSendNotClicked  
  }
  ,[])
   return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      </View>
  );  
}
```

and I just want to confirm is it good practice to checking this kind of condition in useEffect ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi on startup `useEffect` with empty array will be fired and this will be happened during the page load (first time), so you can write your condition there. here is an example:

```
useEffect(()=> {

    // Your condition here

}, []);
```

If you have a variable like `value` then you can write another `useEffect` like below and set that variable (value) in second parameter of `useEffect` as an array

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
useEffect(()=> {

    // Your condition here

}, [value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const y = 5;

//this one will run every time the component renders
//so you could use it to check for anything on the startup
useEffect(()=> {

    // Your condition here

}, []);
```

Otherwise you could add a value or array of values that you want to track for changes so this useEffect bellow Will only run if the  y const changes so you could add an if check there to check if y===5 also this useEffect will run on the first initial of the const y so its perfect in your case

}

```
useEffect(()=> {

    // will run every time y const change and on the first initial of y
    if (y === 5)
    {
      //do your stuff here
    }

}, [y]);
```